Expression for ggplot2 axis title doesn't bold numbers
I'm writing a function that combines text and expressions to form axis titles for an output plot. The problem is that when I try to make it bold, it doesn't apply that styling to numbers. The following code demonstrates the issue.
test_func <- function(x_title) {
  text <- '1'
  
  ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5), aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(x = parse(text = paste('bold(Part ~', text, ' ~', x_title, ')'))) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(face = 'bold'))
}

test_func('Value')


For comparison, see what happens when I input the full title to expression(bold()).
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = expression(bold('Part 1 Value'))) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face = 'bold'))


I also tried adding theme(axis.title = element_text(face = 'bold')), but that made no difference.
How do I get bold to apply to all parts of the expression?

I am not clear about why/how you are using parse(). Would it work to just use paste? in labs(x = paste('Part', text,'Value'))

@SusanSwitzer I use parse because in the "real" function I want an expression so I can do things like subscripting. I didn't include that here because I wanted to focus on the particular part that was giving me trouble.

The problems is that when you parse, the value of "1" in a string looks like a number so it parses to bold(Part ~ 1  ~ boo ). And the plotmath features don't seem to like to bold numbers, but will bold text. So if you wrap the value in quotes, it will stay a string
labs(x = parse(text = paste('bold(Part ~', dQuote(text, F), ' ~', x_title, ')')))

Or you could use bquote and build the string with paste
labs(x = bquote(bold(.(paste('Part', text, x_title)))))


You can use :
text <- expression(bold('1'))

This apparently overrides ggplot2 face parameter, see here.

You can use substitute instead of expression here:
test_func <- function(x_title) {
  text <- '1'
  
  ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5), aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(x = substitute(bold(paste("Part ",text," ", x_title))))
}

test_func('Value')


You could use ggtext and do this with markdown as well. For example:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

test_func <- function(x_title) {
  text <- '1'

  ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5), aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(x = paste0('**Part ', text, ' ', x_title,"**")) +
    theme(axis.title = element_markdown())
}

test_func('Value')


Created on 2024-10-15 with reprex v2.1.1
